# how to update values using switch cases

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4

struct Employee
{
    int no; // Employee ID
    int age; // Employee Age
    double sal; // Employee Salary
};
int main() {

    int option = 0;
    struct Employee emp[SIZE] = { {0} }; // declear the array and initialize the elements to 0
    int counter = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int idstore = 0;
    double salnew = 0;

    printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");


    do
    {
        //print options list
        printf("1. Display Employee information\n");
        printf("2. Add Employee\n");
        printf("3. Update Employee Salary\n");
        printf("4. Remove Employee\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");

        // User input for the options 
        scanf("%d", &option);
        printf("\n");


        switch (option)
        {
        case 0: // Exit the program
            printf("Exiting Employee Data Program. Good Bye!!!");
            break;
        case 1: // Display employee data 

            printf("EMP ID EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
            printf("====== ======= ==========\n");

            for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
            {
                printf("%6d%9d%11.2lf\n", emp[counter].no, emp[counter].age, emp[counter].sal);
            }
            printf("\n");

            break;

        case 2: // Adding Employees

            printf("Adding Employee\n");
            printf("===============\n");

            if (count < SIZE)
            {
                printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                scanf("%d", &emp[count].no);
                printf("Enter Employee Age: ");
                scanf("%d", &emp[count].age);
                printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
                scanf("%lf", &emp[count].sal);
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("ERROR!!! Maximum Number of Employees Reached\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;

        case 3: // Update Employee Salary

            do
            {
                printf("Update Employee Salary\n");
                printf("======================\n");
                printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                scanf("%d", &idstore);

                for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
                {
                    if (idstore == emp[count].no)
                    {
                        printf("The current salary is %lf\n", &emp[count].sal);
                        printf("Enter Employee New Salary: ");
                        scanf("%lf", &emp[count].sal);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found ***\n");
                        printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                        scanf("%d", &idstore);
                    }

                }

            } while (idstore = 0);
            break;

        default:
            printf("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");
        }

    } while (option != 0);


    return 0;
}
```

in my case three im having trouble trying use id numbers entered from my case 2,no matter what i enter in case 3 it gives my error message and it also doesnt show my salary that was also entered in case 2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: a switch statement has nothing to do with updating variables. have you debugged your code and checked what values you're validating against? Also, seeing as this is clearly no Java code, why did you tag it Java?

Comment: Also, what does this question and its code have to do with Java? Please don't spam with unrelated tags.

Comment: Please update the tags on this question

Comment: im trying to update the value of salary based on the first value i entered, but its only showing 000.0 instead of what the salary should currently be based in the id i enter, what do u mean by values im validating against

Comment: In case3 you should use `counter` instead of `count` and your for loop should loop till `count` instead of `SIZE`

Comment: I deleted the java tag for you, in order to help you keep readers in a good mood. If there is a reason for the java tag please explain it and accept my apology.

Comment: You think you have problems in 3 with inout scanned in 2. What makes you think that reading something in 2 was successful, you are e.g. ignoring the return values of all calls to scanf. The problem could also be with the scanf even before the switch construct. Please debug this and provide information to convince us that not one of the many possible mistakes with scanf is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a mistake here:

```
printf("The current salary is %lf\n", &emp[counter].sal);
```

You have to get a variable `emp[counter].sal` value, but not its address `&emp[counter].sal`